# Insert and update stored procedure with parameters and default of zero doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I need help to create an insert stored procedure with parameters, if pass the value for that parameter, then it has to insert or update in database, else it should use a default of zero.

My problem is that when I execute the code below using a `SampleID = 0`, it works... any other `SampleID` does nothing.

Thanks in advance

Execution of the stored procedure:

```
SET NOCOUNT OFF
EXEC SP_Samples '0',  '3'  ,'Pink'
GO
```

Stored procedure code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO              

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Samples]
    (@SamplesID int, 
     @SamplesCategoriesID int,
     @SamplesName nvarchar(50)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (@SamplesID = 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tblSamples ([SamplesName], [SamplesCategoriesID])
        VALUES (@SamplesName, @SamplesCategoriesID)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [tblSamples]
        SET SamplesCategoriesID = @SamplesCategoriesID,
            SamplesName = @SamplesName 
        WHERE SamplesID = @SamplesID
    END      
END
```

Comment: You have a few problems. Two parameters are int but you're passing in varchar values. Lose the double quotes around the numeric parameter values when calling. When you pass a non zero value it runs the update. I'm sure it runs perfectly fine. What behavior makes you think it isn't doing anything? What is your test case?. For example do you have an existing record with `SamplesID=1` that you can test against?

Comment: Thanks Nick, removing the quotes did the trick...the SP is now inserting records for non-zero ID's.thanks for editing code-copy/paste

Comment: I have no idea how it's doing that... it only hits the insert code for values of 0

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thanks Marc, will do. PS-thanks for the code edit, noted for my next post, thanks

Comment: I have voted to close this because none of what has been described makes any consistent sense. Slava has provided some useful info but as a question this isn't useful at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to learn how to debug a stored procedure.
Just temporarily insert following code into your procedure:

```
SELECT @SamplesID, @SamplesCategoriesID, @SamplesName;
```

That is how you will make sure values passed correctly.

Second, for Non-zero cases add following statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblSamples WHERE SamplesID = @SamplesID;
```

That statement should not return zero.

Third, to be 500% sure you are doing it right, pass parameters by name like this:

```
EXEC SP_Samples @SamplesID = 0, @SamplesCategoriesID = 3, @SamplesName = 'Pink';
GO
EXEC SP_Samples @SamplesID = 1, @SamplesCategoriesID = 4, @SamplesName = 'Blue';
GO
```